# What's the difference between using pd.Index vs explicit lists when creating a Series?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

For instance:

```
pd.Series([1,2,3], index = ['a','b','c'])
```

vs

```
pd.Series([1,2,3], index = pd.Index(['a','b','c'])
```

When is it appropriate to use one over the other?

Comment: As per the document of [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.html), index parameter can be: array-like or Index (1d). Do no difference when you are creating index from an array. pd.Index is useful when you use an existing Index to creating a new object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter. The `index` argument accepts any list-like sequence. Regardless of what is passed, [the Series constructor internally calls](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py#L168-L169) the [`ensure_index`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L5234-L5294) function in `core/indexes/base.py`to convert the data to a Series. This function validates the passed index and constructs a `pd.Index` object.

If you pass a `pd.Index` object yourself, `ensure_index` may be able to exit early. Otherwise, it will have to create one from scratch. So there are minor performance benefits, but I would say the gains are at the "seriously, don't worry about it" level.

Idiomatically, all you need do is pass a list (as the simplest option) unless you have good reason to do so otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was just confused why pd.Index existed in the first place but I see how it can be useful with another existing index.

Comment: @NimbleTortoise That is a rather broad question, but it is used for quick lookups and accesses. It is used in many, many functions internally.

Comment: Minor quibble: `ensure_index` does not copy by default, and the `Series` constructor does not tell it to copy, so I don't think a copy will be made if an `Index` is passed as you have the early exit at line 5267. Note that not copying is fine since indexes are immutable.  You'd likely see some minor performance improvements passing an `Index` vs. a list-like, though not enough to really matter for most practical use cases, e.g. time `pd.Series(list('abc') * 10**5, index=pd.Index([4, 5, 6] * 10**5))` vs. `pd.Series(list('abc') * 10**5, index=[4, 5, 6] * 10**5)`

Comment: @root Appreciate the comment. Yes, that was oversight, thank you.

Comment: no worries; thanks for all your work answering `pandas` questions!